# Convert value from UNIX to DateTime in DatagridView column

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I am using the SQLite database for my application, and it does not have the DateTime format. Therefore, the values are stored in UNIX format, and the information displayed with the DataGridView. What function can convert UNIX to DateTime format and show it in the DataGridView?

I have tried to convert this column in DataTable, but in the database, this column has an INT format, so I had a mistake. I also tried to add a new column to the DataTable and fill this column with Expression.

```cs
string sql = "Select * from Main";

var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = FistDB.db;Version = 3");
conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);

da.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the SQL request to get the time stamp in the desired format:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, strftime(requred_time_format, Col3), ... FROM MAIN
```

Use "DATETIME(Col3, 'LOCALTIME')" to convert the time stamp to the local time if required.

Refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

In the end you always want to handle time stamps in a `DateTime` struct, so it is best to convert your UNIX epoch as early as possible in the pipeline. This will handle  time zone info, summer daytime saving and culture info correctly (and more).
Here is your one-liner:

```cs
var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1687006136).DateTime;
```

PS: make sure to use `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` for milliseconds

more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-7.0

PS2: The time abstraction API will [change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8) in .NET 8, but it will not affect this use case.